# Flutter: How to get asset path (video) for File class

Tags: flutter, file, assets, filepath

I saved a video in my asset folder and i am trying to get the video using the File class.

For example:

```
Final File video = File(String path);
```

So my question is where can i find the String path?

I already added this file to the pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - assets/mbf.mp4
```

Thank you

Answer

```
getVideo() async {
var response = await rootBundle.load('assets/mbf.mp4');
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var file = File("${directory.path}/mbf.mp4"); 
file.writeAsBytesSync(response.buffer.asUint8List());

//Use it with VideoPlayer

controller = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
  ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
  ..setLooping(true)
  ..initialize().then((_) => controller.play());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need copy file to device and then get path of file.

See exampl code:

```
void _copyAssetToLocal() async {
try {
  var content = await rootBundle.load("assets/intro.mp4");
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var file = File("${directory.path}/intro.mp4");
  file.writeAsBytesSync(content.buffer.asUint8List());
  loadIntroVideoMethod(file.path);
} catch (e) {
  
}}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i get the file in the  VideoPlayerController.file(????).

Answer (score 0):

The path is `assets/mbf.mp4`, but it is not compatible with `File` constructor.

See [Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) for details.

Using [AssetBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html) data can be loaded, which of course can be written to a file.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/mbf.mp4');
```

Play video directly from assets use [VideoPlayerController.asset](https://pub.dev/documentation/video_player/latest/video_player/VideoPlayerController/VideoPlayerController.asset.html) constructor.

```
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/mbf.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
```

Comment: Yes thank you appreciate your time. But i actually want to use file instead of asset. So i can use the video for other packeges too. File might be better. Do you have a solution for that ?